# Examples of non-commutative rings in nature

Tags: soft-question, applications

So this may sound kinda vague but my point is: mathematics can be applied in several ways to our understanding of nature and often even things that seems to be totally abstract can be, more or less rigorously and more or less naturally, successufully applied. Said that (abstract) algebra too applies to the world around us, so I was wondering if there is some practical examples of structure in our every day life that resembles the one of non commutative rings. Any examples or reference will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Particle spins are finite-dimensional weight representations of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, whence also of the noncommutative ring $U\big(\mathfrak{su}(2)\big)$ (the universal enveloping algebra of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$).

Comment: @Batominovski this sound very interesting!

Comment: I am interested in seeing the first answer which does not based on geometry with real numbers (which quaternions and real/complex Lie algebras basically fall into.)

Comment: @rschwieb me too!

Comment: I once read a differential geometry text that included a sentence along the lines of "If translations and rotations commuted with each other, you could do all of your steering before you leave the driveway."

Answer (score 4):

The [Hamilton quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) are noncommutative and are routinely used in [computer vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_vision) to model rotations. That's as close to *nature* as you can get!

Comment: I was thinking to that too! Quaternions are a really interesting topic.

Comment: @RenatoFaraone Really this plays off the fact that we find "geometry" to be a good illustration of "nature," particularly geometry with real numbers. $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb H$ all have useful interpretations used by engineers and physicists in terms of geometry and Lie algebra.

Answer (score 2):

When I think "noncommutative ring", the canonical examples I think of are the $n \times n$ matrices.  And phenomena that can be described by matrices are *everywhere*, including not only "nature" (whatever that means) but also all other aspects of "everyday life".